# Alignment of an equation

Tags: equations, align, amsmath

```
\begin{align} 
\begin{split}
\label{eq:1.20}
\left( \frac{U}{2}\begin{bmatrix}
-1+\beta & 1-\beta & 0 & 0 & \hdots & 0 \\
-1-\beta & 2\beta & 1-\beta & 0 & \hdots & 0 \\
0 & -1-\beta & 2\beta & 1-\beta & \hdots & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1-\beta & 1+\beta \\
\end{bmatrix} + \frac{a}{h^e}\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & \hdots & 0 \\
-1 & 2 & -1 & 0 & \hdots & 0 \\
0 & -1 & 2 & -1 & \hdots & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 &  1 \\
\end{bmatrix} \right) \begin{bmatrix} T_1 \\ T_2 \\ T_3 \\ \vdots \\ T_N 
\end{bmatrix} \\ = \frac{fh^e}{2}\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ 2 \\ \vdots \\ 1 
\end{bmatrix} 
\end{split}
\end{align}
```

[image]

How can I get the part after the equal sign in the centre of the page?

Answer (score 5):

i would write your equation like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{multline}
\label{eq:1.20}
\left(\frac{U}{2}\begin{bmatrix}
    -1+\beta & 1-\beta  & 0       & 0       & \dots    & 0 \\
    -1-\beta & 2\beta   & 1-\beta & 0       & \dots    & 0 \\
    0        & -1-\beta & 2\beta  & 1-\beta & \dots    & 0 \\
    \vdots   & \vdots   & \vdots  & \vdots  & \vdots   & \vdots \\
    0        & 0        & 0       & 0       & -1-\beta & 1+\beta \\
            \end{bmatrix}\right. + \\
\left.\frac{a}{h^e}\begin{bmatrix}
    1  & -1 & 0     & 0     & \dots & 0 \\
    -1 & 2  & -1    & 0     & \dots & 0 \\
    0  & -1 & 2     & -1    & \dots & 0 \\
    \vdots  & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
    0  & 0  & 0     & 0     & -1    &  1 \\
            \end{bmatrix} \right) \begin{bmatrix} 
                                  T_1 \\ T_2 \\ T_3 \\ \vdots \\ T_N
                                    \end{bmatrix} 
    = \frac{fh^e}{2}\begin{bmatrix} 
                1 \\ 2 \\ 2 \\ \vdots \\ 1
                    \end{bmatrix}
\end{multline}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use `gathered` to centre them but it is too wide, I would use `multline`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    \label{eq:1.20}
  \begin{gathered}
\left( \frac{U}{2}\begin{bmatrix}
-1+\beta & 1-\beta & 0 & 0 & \hdots & 0 \\
-1-\beta & 2\beta & 1-\beta & 0 & \hdots & 0 \\
0 & -1-\beta & 2\beta & 1-\beta & \hdots & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1-\beta & 1+\beta \\
\end{bmatrix} + \frac{a}{h^e}\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & \hdots & 0 \\
-1 & 2 & -1 & 0 & \hdots & 0 \\
0 & -1 & 2 & -1 & \hdots & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 &  1 \\
\end{bmatrix} \right) \begin{bmatrix} T_1 \\ T_2 \\ T_3 \\ \vdots \\ T_N 
\end{bmatrix} \\ = \frac{fh^e}{2}\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ 2 \\ \vdots \\ 1 
\end{bmatrix}
  \end{gathered}
\end{equation}


\begin{multline}
    \label{eq:1.20}
\left( \frac{U}{2}\begin{bmatrix}
-1+\beta & 1-\beta & 0 & 0 & \hdots & 0 \\
-1-\beta & 2\beta & 1-\beta & 0 & \hdots & 0 \\
0 & -1-\beta & 2\beta & 1-\beta & \hdots & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1-\beta & 1+\beta \\
\end{bmatrix}\right.\\
 + \frac{a}{h^e}\left.\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & \hdots & 0 \\
-1 & 2 & -1 & 0 & \hdots & 0 \\
0 & -1 & 2 & -1 & \hdots & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 &  1 \\
\end{bmatrix}\right)\begin{bmatrix} T_1 \\ T_2 \\ T_3 \\ \vdots \\ T_N 
\end{bmatrix} \\
 = \frac{fh^e}{2}\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ 2 \\ \vdots \\ 1 
\end{bmatrix}
\end{multline}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Two other variants with `gathered`, wher the equation number is aligned with the bottom row:

- a smaller value of `\arraycolsep` and using the `medsize` environment from `nccmath` makes the equation fit the default margins
- if you don't need the default margins, loading `geometry` gives more sensible margins, and only a smaller value of \arraycolsep is used to fit the margins.

A code with both possibilities (and geometry loaded):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools, nccmath, mleftright}
\usepackage{bigstrut}
\newenvironment{bmmatrix}{\begin{medsize}\begin{bmatrix}}%
{\end{bmatrix}\end{medsize}}

\begin{document}
\mbox{}
\begin{equation}
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{3pt}
    \label{eq:1.20}
  \begin{gathered}[b]
\mathclap{\mleft( \mfrac{U}{2}\begin{bmmatrix}
-1+\beta & 1-\beta & 0 & 0 & \hdots & 0 \bigstrut[t]\\
-1-\beta & 2\beta & 1-\beta & 0 & \hdots & 0 \\
0 & -1-\beta & 2\beta & 1-\beta & \hdots & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1-\beta & 1+\beta \\
\end{bmmatrix} + \mfrac{a}{h^e}\begin{bmmatrix}
1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & \hdots & 0 \bigstrut[t] \\
-1 & 2 & -1 & 0 & \hdots & 0 \\
0 & -1 & 2 & -1 & \hdots & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 1 \\
\end{bmmatrix} \mright) \begin{bmmatrix} T_1 \bigstrut[t]\\ T_2 \\ T_3 \\ \vdots \\ T_N
\end{bmmatrix}} \\[1ex] = \mfrac{fh^e}{2}\begin{bmmatrix} 1 \bigstrut[t]\\ 2 \\ 2 \\ \vdots \\ 1
\end{bmmatrix}
  \end{gathered}
\end{equation}
\vspace{3ex}

\begin{equation}
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{3pt}
    \label{eq:1.20}
  \begin{gathered}[b]
\left( \frac{U}{2}\begin{bmatrix}
-1+\beta & 1-\beta & 0 & 0 & \hdots & 0 \\
-1-\beta & 2\beta & 1-\beta & 0 & \hdots & 0 \\
0 & -1-\beta & 2\beta & 1-\beta & \hdots & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1-\beta & 1+\beta \\
\end{bmatrix} + \frac{a}{h^e}\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & \hdots & 0 \\
-1 & 2 & -1 & 0 & \hdots & 0 \\
0 & -1 & 2 & -1 & \hdots & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix} \right) \begin{bmatrix} T_1 \\ T_2 \\ T_3 \\ \vdots \\ T_N
\end{bmatrix} \\ = \frac{fh^e}{2}\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ 2 \\ \vdots \\ 1
\end{bmatrix}
  \end{gathered}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
\begin{align} 
\begin{split}
\label{eq:1.20}
\left( \frac{U}{2}\begin{bmatrix}
-1+\beta & 1-\beta & 0 & 0 & \hdots & 0 \\
-1-\beta & 2\beta & 1-\beta & 0 & \hdots & 0 \\
0 & -1-\beta & 2\beta & 1-\beta & \hdots & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1-\beta & 1+\beta \\
\end{bmatrix}\right. &+ \left.\frac{a}{h^e}\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & \hdots & 0 \\
-1 & 2 & -1 & 0 & \hdots & 0 \\
0 & -1 & 2 & -1 & \hdots & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 &  1 \\
\end{bmatrix} \right) \begin{bmatrix} T_1 \\ T_2 \\ T_3 \\ \vdots \\ T_N 
\end{bmatrix}
\\ &= \frac{fh^e}{2}\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ 2 \\ \vdots \\ 1 
\end{bmatrix} 
\end{split}
\end{align}
```

Hopes this helps

Comment: you would need a very wide page for that layout (it is 100pt wider than the default width in `article` for example)